# Moving Stopped Minecarts with Powered Rails

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If a minecart is at rest on a deactivated powered rail, simply powering the rail will not make it move.  The minecart must be kickstarted somehow, e.g. by a player pushing it in the desired direction.

I'd like to make a traditional train station, where the carts stop briefly at a platform before speeding away.  However, due to this limitation, the process can not be fully automated.

What are some techniques to start minecarts from a full stop without any direct influence by the player?  If possible, I'd like to avoid sloped rails because they look bad next to a platform.

Comment: I think sloped rails ARE the only reliable way to do this.  Probably the introduction of pistons will help, though.

Comment: @Shinrai Perhaps some convoluted design involving a minecart coming up from behind and bumping it?

Comment: Yeah, but that minecart has to get started SOMEHOW...

Comment: that second minecart could easily come in from a booster track, and use a detector rail to switch the tracks at the end.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The basic principle of starting minecarts with Powered Rails is that the minecart needs to "know which way to go". By this, I mean there must only be one possible way for the minecart to move.

A sloped Powered Rail works because the minecart knows to move downhill. Another way to do this without sloping the rail is to **put a solid block on one side of the Powered Rail**. By doing this, the minecart should start moving the other way when the rail is powered.

Comment: This explains why my minecart won't move if it isn't -right-  next to the wall on the powered rail. That has been bugging me for days, thanks for the answer!

Comment: With pistons it's possible to automate the block placement. Is that aspect still worth an extra answer?