# Repeater powers the rail but cart is not starting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm having some problem with the start system for a cart based on repeater and powered rails combo.

Basically I can see that they are getting power but the cart doesn't move at all, when it's parked on this end.

If I move the repeater to the side and put a stone block behind the rail, the cart is doing like 1 cm movement but still not working.

Any ideas how to get this schema to work ?

[image: redstone schema]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving Stopped Minecarts with Powered Rails](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25039/moving-stopped-minecarts-with-powered-rails)

Comment: yes same problem, the part of the question is why putting a block on the end of the rail doesn't really solve the problem; the cart needs like 5 power cycles to start

Comment: as well as doing it park in a slop rail; 5-6 cycles to start it all the time; @pppery

Comment: Are you saying putting a solid block at the end doesn't work for you?

Comment: If the pulse is too short, the block won't suffice. But without the block the cart doesn't have any "bias" regarding which direction it should start moving so it won't even budge.

Comment: @Joachim it's doesn't solve the problem with the cart not starting but with it the cart start moving on like 1 cm and requires like 5 restarts to move from the powered rail

Comment: @VladimirZaguzin: The pulse is too short. Repeater on 4 ticks is completely sufficient to get the minecart going with 1 block next to it. Even 3 ticks suffice. [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZjLt.png)

Comment: Of course if you run the redstone like in your pic next to the solid block, the block will power the redstone, redstone will power the repeater and you have a permanently powered piece.